# SwiftUI - Shapes in ForEach view with different stroke color and line width Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have an array of `Path` and I have a custom shape.

```
struct MyShape: Shape {
    var path: Path

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        path
    }
}
```

I am drawing multiple shapes using a `ForEach` view. I want to assign different line widths and colors to each view

```
struct MyView: View {

    @State private var paths: [Path] = []
    @State private var lineWidths: [Double] = []
    @State private var colors: [Color] = []

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<paths.count, id: \.self) { index in
                MyShape(path: paths[index])
                    .stroke(lineWidth: lineWidths[index])
                    .foregroundColor(colors[index])
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The paths are drawing fine but all of the shapes are taking linewidth and color the same as the first shape. For example, if I have the colors

```
@State private var lineWidhts: [Double] = [4.0, 10.0, 20.0]
@State private var colors: [Color] = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.yellow]
```

All of the shapes have 4.0 line width and red color instead of having different colors.

Comment: probably a typo, you are missing a `)` in `.stroke(lineWidth: lineWidths[index])`, note the last `)`. Or the code you are showing us is not the code that creates your issue.

Comment: show some example `Path`  and enough code that together reproduce your problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are using:
 `@State private var lineWidhts: [Double] = [4.0, 10.0, 20.0]` like you say, 
then you have another typo, `lineWidhts` instead of `lineWidths` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var paths: [Path] = [Path(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90),cornerRadius: 10),Path(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 110, y: 110, width: 90, height: 90), cornerRadius: 10), Path(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 220, y: 220, width: 90, height: 90), cornerRadius: 10)]
    @State private var lineWidhts: [Double] = [4.0, 10.0, 20.0]
    @State private var colors: [Color] = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.yellow]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<paths.count, id: \.self) { index in
                MyShape(path: paths[index])
                    .stroke(lineWidth: lineWidhts[index])
                    .foregroundColor(colors[index])
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I try with this code and works fine.